# mysql data table how while fetching record count plus one for field name

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatable, counter, fetch

I have this code here:

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($itemavailablequeryres))
{
echo "
<tr>
<td>$record['itemid']</td>
<td>$record['code']</td>
<td>$record['name']</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='input'></td>
</tr> ";
}
```

Now the output in HTML would be:

```
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>105</td>
                    <td>t-racks</td>
                    <td>Mic splitter</td>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' name='input'></td>
                </tr>
```

For each record of the database.

How can I implement a counter so that the input name will be +1 after each record?

So the output will be:

```
<tr>
...
<td><input type='checkbox' name='input1'></td>
...
</tr>
<tr>
...
<td><input type='checkbox' name='input2'></td>
...
</tr>
<tr>
...
<td><input type='checkbox' name='input3'></td>
...
</tr>
<tr>
...
<td><input type='checkbox' name='input4'></td>
...
</tr>
```

etc, depending on how many records are fetched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array of checkboxes

```
<td><input type='checkbox' name='input[]'></td>
```

If you still want to do with the counter

you could do like this

```
$row =1;
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($itemavailablequeryres))
{
   echo "
    <tr>
    <td>$record['itemid']</td>
    <td>$record['code']</td>
    <td>$record['name']</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='input{$row}' ></td>
    </tr> ";
    $row++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add a counter to your code:

```
$i = 1;
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($itemavailablequeryres))
{
    echo "
    <tr>
    <td>$record['itemid']</td>
    <td>$record['code']</td>
    <td>$record['name']</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='input "'. $i . '"'></td>
    </tr> ";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this with a count :

```
$count=0;
while {
 $count++;
 echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="input'.$count.'"></td>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that :

```
$counter=1;
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($itemavailablequeryres))
{
echo "
<tr>
<td>$record['itemid']</td>
<td>$record['code']</td>
<td>$record['name']</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='input'".($counter++)."></td>
</tr> ";
}
```